# Existence of solution of the system of inequalities

Tags: inequality, euclidean-geometry

I want to find a simple way to determine, if the following system of inequalities has a non-trivial  solution :

$a_{1,1}x_1+a_{1,2}x_2+\ldots+a_{1,n}x_n \le 0$

$a_{2,1}x_1+a_{2,2}x_2+\ldots+a_{2,n}x_n \le 0$

$\vdots$

$a_{p,1}x_1+a_{p,2}x_2+\ldots+a_{p,n}x_n \le 0$

$b_{1,1}x_1+b_{1,2}x_2+\ldots+b_{1,n}x_n  < 0$

$b_{2,1}x_1+b_{2,2}x_2+\ldots+b_{2,n}x_n  < 0$

$\vdots$

$b_{q,1}x_1+b_{q,2}x_2+\ldots+b_{q,n}x_n  < 0,$

including the case, when $p=0$ or $q=0$ (i.e. all inequalities are strict or non-strict). Non-trivial solution means, that there exists $i$ for which $x_i\not = 0$.

It is assumed, that $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ is to be from real euclidean space.

Comment: Are we to assume $p+q=n$?

Comment: I don't really know much about the kinds of algorithms used in these problems, but this field is called "linear programming." (Sorry if you already know that.) You may find discussion of these problems in a computer-oriented book on linear programming.

Comment: Indeed, linear programming involves conditions of mentioned type, by the main task of linear programming is solving of optimization problem. I don't have any optimization related problem and interested only in existence of solution.